# concourse complains about inputs for on_success

Tags: concourse

concourse complains about inputs for on_success: unknown/extra keys:   - jobs[1].plan[2].on_success.inputs

This just happened on a recent upgrade, wasn't always the case. I'm using 3.2.1

```
  - put: deploy-to-cloud
    inputs:
     - name: some-input
    params
      manifest: manifest.yml
      path: some-input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a lot of cleanup done for the pipeline configuration. It has become more strict.

Within a `put`, you cannot define `inputs`. A `put` get's any available resource automagically mounted into it. In your use-case, `some-input` is already in there.

```
- put: deploy-to-cloud
    params
      manifest: manifest.yml
      path: some-input
```